# Junit: local variables and void methods

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I'm fairly new to unit testing and have been reading a lot of material online, but I'm having  a little trouble figuring stuff out.

For example: If I have the following piece of code :

```
public class RandomClass
{
  int a = 4;
  public void foo(Object obj)
  {
    if(a == 4)
    {
      AnotherObject anotherObj = new AnotherObject();
      anotherObj.setAttribute(obj.getFiled());
      //Method call that will be suppressed 
      Anotherclass.anotherMethod(anotherObj);
    } 
  }
}
```

I thought of writing my junit test case like this:

```
@Test
public void testFoo()
{
  int a=4;
  RandomClass randomClass = new RandomClass();
  Object object = new Object();
  object.setField("hey");
  randomClass.foo(object);
}
```

I have a couple of questions here. 
How exactly do I set the integer a from my junit? The way I'm setting it right now doesn't the unit test case any impact. When I debug the unit test, the value of a is NULL so it never passes the if condition!

Also, the method foo returns a void so what can I possibly test/assert?

Comment: Your code is not correct. If variable `a` is not static in `RandomClass`, you will not be able to check its value in static method `foo`

Comment: Oh I see, how can I check a's value if foo isn't a static method?

Comment: it is not a junit related case, it is case of accessing class field and encapsulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two major techniques when writing unit tests:

1. Checking the external contract of your class under test. Meaning: you try to write testcases for *RandomClass* that know **nothing** about *AnotherClass*. Instead, your test code only observes behavior of *RandomClass* objects. In other words: you really don't care about the internal implementation details of *RandomClass* - because all the things you "want to see" can be observed by checking what *RandomClass* objects return when you call methods with specific parameters. Occasionally you get there by adding (package protected) getter methods that allow you to inspect some internal state of your class under test.
2. But sometimes that might not be "good enough"; for example when you know that your class under test **must** be using some other objects to get its job done. In such situations, you should be looking into **mocking** objects. In your case, you might want to create a mocked instance of **AnotherClass**; and then you would use *dependency injection* in order to **provide** that object to your class under test.

You see, you actually wrote "hard to test" code - because you are calling **new** for *AnotherClass* in your production code. That doesn't seem like a big deal, but depending on what *AnotherClass* is about ... you really shouldn't do that!

In any case; I recommend you to look into these [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79) to learn how to write code that works better for unit testing.

Answer (score 1):

A test normally starts with a "setup", "prepare", or "arrange" step, where it creates or modifies the object under test so that it is in the state needed by that particular test.

So, if field `a` in the `RandomClass` object needs to have a value `4` (for example), then the test needs to either create the object passing this value as a constructor argument, *or* to set the value in the object by calling a setter method or by directly accessing the field. In the worst case, you might need to use Reflection to set the field, but that would indicate a design issue in the class being tested.

The next step is to exercise the code under test. This is the "act" step, in the "Arrange, Act, Assert" terminology (AAA, for short).

Finally, the final step is to "assert" (verify) the code being tested did what is was supposed to do.

If the method being tested has `void` return type, then the test should verify it did what was expected either through *state* verification or through *behavior* verification.

In the first case, the test would call some getter method in the object under test, and use it in an "assert" of some kind (for example, an `assertEquals(expectedValue, actualValue)`).

In the second case, the test would use some *mocking* library in order to verify that expected calls were made from the code under test to one or more dependencies (other objects or classes on which the class under test depends). For example, here the test could verify that `RandomClass#foo` did actually call `Anotherclass.anotherMethod(...)`.

Comment: All the answers here are very helpful. Thanks so much!